# Problem with font in Skype

Tags: 13.04, fonts, skype

Has anybody experienced problems like the below in Skype:

[image: It looks like that]

The font of the time is broken. I have googled all day and found nothing similar to it. All other font in Skype is okay except the time.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail

Comment: Interesting conversation :) I had the same problem and seems that changing the LC_NUMERIC value helps, so I believe this solves your problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/310990/borked-encoding-in-ubuntu-13-04-for-slovak-language .