# Borked encoding in Ubuntu 13.04 for Slovak language

Tags: 13.04, locale, encoding

I'm having the same issue as described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2151383). A workaround, that **does not work**, as I got to know [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1394236), since Ubuntu no longer uses locale.gen, has been suggested in the same thread.

Can someone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a bug in the Slovak locale with respect to the LC_NUMERIC category. Try to add this line to your `~/.profile` file:

```
export LC_NUMERIC=en_DK.UTF-8
```

(assuming that en_DK.utf8 is one of the available locales according to the `locale -a` command)

Comment: That didn't solve the problem unfortunately. Might I add, that I couldn't even find a file entitled .profile.

Comment: .profile is in /home, i.e. /home/[username]/.profile

Comment: Nope, double checked, no such file or directory.

Comment: Strange, since that file is always created when you create a new user account. Anyway, then I suggest that you simply create it manually, with the suggested line as its only contents.

Comment: Gunnar you the man! It works this way, thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. Saw the bug https://launchpad.net/bugs/1173138, and hope that the real fix will be implemented soon.

Comment: To see that file (/.profile) you have to check "show hidden files" in "view" when browsing files in a file manager.